# In Angular models, can you switch value type between JSON Object and String?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, type-conversion, angular-ngmodel

I have an application at work that I am working on that requires me to display various fields based on the value of the associated `rule.itemType`. The issue I am coming across is that I am unable to modify the model data in an `ng-repeat` if the previous set value in `rule.value` was a `String` object that now is displaying fields that require an `Object`. When I try to assign new values it returns: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'course' of ABC123`.

I did find that if the value was an `Object` it would display it as a `String` of `[object Object]`, which I am assuming comes from the `Object.prototype.toString()` function I was reading about, and if changed will replace `rule.value` with a new `String` object. Even though this direction works, if I am needing to do a `String` to `Object` we end up back at the above mentioned issue.

I have attached sample code to demonstrate what I am trying to do below plus some data. I also forked, modified, and linked a replier's Plunker so you can see it in action:

http://plnkr.co/edit/v4gSyc6MbYeGGyJppvnc?p=preview

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.rules = [
    {id: 1, itemType: 'CS', value: {course: 'ABC', number: '123'}},
    {id: 2, itemType: 'SA', value: 'ABC123'}
  ];
});
```

HTML, with Angular v1.3.0:

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl as app">
    <div ng-repeat="rule in rules">
      Rule {{$index+1}}
      <!-- Change the itemType for the rule -->
      <select ng-model="rule.itemType">
        <option value="SA">String</option>
        <option value="CS">Object</option>
      </select>
      <!-- Fields shown if rule.itemType (SA: String, CS: Object) -->
      <input type="text" ng-if="rule.itemType === 'SA'" ng-model="rule.value" />
      <span ng-if="rule.itemType === 'CS'">
        <input ng-model="rule.value.course" />
        <input ng-model="rule.value.number" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Update 1:**

Added the suggestion from Ryan Randall to use `ng-change='changeType(rule)` which provides the appropriate behavior I was looking for, example plunker below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bFahZj?p=preview

JavaScript Changes:

```
  // Contributed by: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702691/949704
  $scope.typeChange = function (rule) {
    if (rule.itemType === 'CS') rule.value = {};
    if (rule.itemType === 'SA') rule.value = '';
  };
```

HTML Changes:

```
      <!-- Change the itemType for the rule -->
      <select ng-model="rule.itemType" ng-change="changeType(rule)">
        <option value="SA">String</option>
        <option value="CS">Object</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: I updated the code to include the root of the issue, which was the itemType when being changed it would show the right inputs but not accept the values. Also I added a plunker.

Comment: I have edited the question to be a little more clear about the subject matter at hand. I also want to say thanks, I am reading the link you gave me and seeing if it can help me figure out the answer to my issue. I am currently experimenting with the example code they provide, etc.

Comment: Saw your Tweet about this, seems fine to me. Don't worry about the odd downvote, they are quite normal. Questions are for posterity though, so I've edited out the voting commentary and about being new. Questions are best pithy and sticking to the problem at hand. +1

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the tips! I will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid the issue you're having is to explicitly set rule.value when rule.itemType changes.

Here's a working plunker containing the tweaks: http://plnkr.co/edit/rMfeBe?p=preview

The following has been added to the select:

```
ng-change="typeChange(rule)"
```

And the following has been added to the controller:

```
$scope.typeChange = function(rule) {
    if (rule.itemType === 'CS') rule.value = {};
    if (rule.itemType === 'SA') rule.value = '';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand your question mate...  Can you please specify exactly what you did to get that error because it's not happening to me.. (maybe also the browser you're on)

Seems to work fine, see below plunkr

```
'http://plnkr.co/edit/04huDKRSIr2YLtjItZRK?p=preview'
```

Comment: I have updated and attached a corrected version at: http://plnkr.co/edit/bFahZj?p=preview